# Auto move to next tab when an input fills with 1 integer

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyup

How to move to next input field when filled up with 1 integer. When I enter an integer in input field, it doesn't move to next input field

```js
jq = $

jq(".pc").keyup(function() {
  var nextItem = parseInt(this.id) + 1;
  console.log(nextItem);
  jq(this).next('.pc').focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <input class="form-control pc" id="1" type="text" name="pc1" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <input class="form-control pc" id="2" type="text" name="pc2" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <input class="form-control pc" id="3" type="text" name="pc3" />
</div>
```

Comment: [mcve] - _"Describe the problem. **"It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem**. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Use a brief but descriptive summary of your problem as the title of your question."_

Comment: `jq(this).next('.pc')` there is not another element next to `.pc` so `next(".pc")` is `null`. The fastest way to fix this (not the best) is by using `parent()` and `find()` => `jq(this).parent().next().find('.pc')`

Comment: What should happen when you remove a value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pc` aren't siblings, you'll need to go up to parent then go to its sibling to find `.pc`

so you need to use  `$(this).parent().next().find('.pc').focus();`

```js
$(".pc").on('keyup', function() {
  const nextItem = parseInt(this.id) + 1;
  $(this).parent().next().find('.pc').focus();
  console.log(nextItem);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <input class="form-control pc" id="1" type="text" name="pc1" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <input class="form-control pc" id="2" type="text" name="pc2" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <input class="form-control pc" id="3" type="text" name="pc3" />
</div>
```

Comment: Is value `""` also one integer?

Answer (score 1):

**this code will work event when changed the HTML**
I have created this function for you and used the `onkeyup` event.

*this will allow you to disable this action on the last input.*

advice: use a clean name on using objects or elements for example change `pc` to `personalCode` :P

**this will help you in the future**

```js
function jumpToNextPcInput(currentIndex){
  currentIndex++;
  document.getElementById('pc'+currentIndex).focus();
 }
```

```html
<div class="col-md-2">
  <input type="text" class="form-control pc" onkeyup="jumpToNextPcInput(1)" id="pc1" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <input type="text" class="form-control pc" onkeyup="jumpToNextPcInput(2)" id="pc2" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <input type="text" class="form-control pc" id="pc3" />
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for advice :) I will use clean name next time. Thanks For your response, i will try this shortly